# Pulling a lot of files from a remote host using ssh, find, and rsync

Tags: bash, shell, unix, rsync

I am trying to integrate the following commands to pull a lot of files from a remote host, without sending duplicate files

```
for FILE in $(ssh $FTP_USER@$FTP_HOST find $REMOTE_DIR -maxdepth 1 -name "*$FILEGROUP*.dat.gz" -mmin -30);
do
  echo "[`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`] + Transferring (ignore-existing): $FILE"
  rsync -a --ignore-existing $FTP_USER@$FTP_HOST:$FILE $LOCAL_DIR
done
```

However, it seems to be connecting to the FTP_HOST each and every iteration of the FOR LOOP. Is there a way to connect once, pull the all the results of the FIND command into an array, then cycle rsync through that array?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my complex command that does that:

```
ssh "$FTP_USER@$FTP_HOST" \
    $(printf '%q ' \
        find "$REMOTE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$FILEGROUP*.dat.gz" -mmin -30 -printf '%P\0' \
    ) |
rsync -avh0 --files-from=- "$FTP_USER@$FTP_HOST":"$REMOTE_DIR" "$LOCAL_DIR"
```

**Explanation**: We want to run the following command on the remote side, to generate a null-separated list of the relative paths of all files that we want to copy:

```
find "$REMOTE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$FILEGROUP*.dat.gz" -mmin -30 -printf '%P\0'
```

In order to run it remotely, we use the following trick:

```
ssh "$FTP_USER@$FTP_HOST" $(printf '%q ' ......)
```

to ensure that all arguments are properly escaped so that they are not interpreted by the remote shell that ssh will invoke.

Finally, we pipe the list of the the file names into `rsync`. We use `-0 --files-from=-` to tell `rsync` to read the file list from its stdin and that it should treat it as a null-separated list.